# Html / javascript - Dropdown selection not working with Submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to using a dropdown and an input box and then submit both.
For some reason, it is not

```js
function watchForm() {
  $('.decisions').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault;
    const state = $('.js-query-states').val();
    console.log(state)
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="decisions">

  <select class="states js-query-states">
    <option value="">Choose a state</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <label for="number">How many</label>
  <input type="input" name="number" id="number" value=5>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Why are you listening clicks on the form?

Comment: Where do you call `watchForm()`?

Comment: You're missing the parentheses after `event.preventDefault`, so you're not calling the function.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the input box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues here:

- You need to listen to the Form [`.submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event instead of `click()`.
- Also, you are missing the parentheses `()` after `event.preventDefault`.
- Also, it seems that the event handler is inside the `watchForm()` function, but it is not called anywhere. So, you can remove that function and add the `.submit()` event handler directly.

```js
$('.decisions').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const state = $('.js-query-states').val();
  console.log(state)

  const number = $('#number').val();
  console.log(number)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="decisions">
  <select class="states js-query-states" required>
    <option value="">Choose a state</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <label for="number">How many</label>
  <input type="input" name="number" id="number" value=5>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you. I have watchForm() called but just didn't include it in the code I sent. looks like the () after the event.prevent Default() was the main issue but thanks for all the pointers

Answer (score 0):

It should be **event.preventDefault()** like **Barmar** said. Also it's good to have **submit** event for the form.

Answer (score 0):

To submit the value of the "select" DOM element you must set the "name" attribute and then, "submit" button will include it when you clicked on it

```
<form class = "decisions">

    <select class="states js-query-states" name="state">
        <option value= "">Choose a state</option>
        <option value= "AL">Alabama</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <label for= "number">How many</label>
    <input type = "input" name = "number" id= "number" value = 5>
    <input type="submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```